# Rsync hangs when transfering large files on an bad connection

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I've been having problems transferring files over a pretty bad connection (I'm trying to upload a file on a cloud server) via rsync.

The rsync essentially hangs after about a minute or so. This is the way I'm trying to perform the upload:

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh" ~/target.war root@my-remote-server:~/
```

There is no error message or other info. It simply hangs displaying something like:

```
 7307264  14%   92.47kB/s    0:07:59
```

Ping-ing the remote endpoint doesn't seem to be loosing packages as far as I see.

Any help on how to overcome this problem would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Have the same problem - no solution for moths... :-(

Comment: I am running into it too, the only switch you're using that I wasn't is --progress. Discovered - by chance - that you can make it resume the transfer: pause (Ctrl+Z) and reactivate it. I used 'bg' after Ctrl+Z to resume it in the background, 'fg' probably works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `--partial` option keeps partially transferred files if the transfer is interrupted. You could use it to try again without having to transfer the whole file again.

In fact, there is the `-P` option, which is equivalent to `--partial --progress`. According to `rsync`'s man page, "Its purpose is to make it much easier to specify these two options for a long transfer that may be interrupted."